# There are no commands defined in the "app" namespace Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

estoy aprendiendo sobre laravel con algunos video cursos y documentación en la web pero resulta que cuando trato de cambiarle el namespace a mi aplicacion me sale el siguiente error

> 'There are no commands defined in the "app" namespace.'

He probado algunas soluciones que encontre en interner como actualizar el composer o el laravel-permissions pero no ha funcionado.

La version de Laravel que estoy usando es la 6.

Comment: puedes incluir algo de código para saber el contexto en el cual haces lo que dices?? ve a [ask] para mas información...

Comment: Hola Camilo. Sería más útil que agregues el código y lo que has intentado hacer en él para dar una mejor idea y poder ayudarte de mejor manera. ¡Saludos!

Comment: Acabo de revisar instalando la version de Laravel 6.0 y me doy cuenta que sacaron el comando app:namespace de la lista de artisan. cosa que no aparece en el Release Notes.(pienso que esto fue una medida para unificar el nombre a solamente App)

Answer (score 1):

Investigando un poco encontré lo siguiente:

**Primero**

Si ejecutas el comando `php artisan` en un proyecto de Laravel 6, verás el siguiente listado de comandos:

```
C:\Users\user\api>php artisan
Laravel Framework 6.0.3

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]       The environment the command should run under
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more
verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  clear-compiled       Remove the compiled class file
  down                 Put the application into maintenance mode
  env                  Display the current framework environment
  help                 Displays help for a command
  inspire              Display an inspiring quote
  list                 Lists commands
  migrate              Run the database migrations
  optimize             Cache the framework bootstrap files
  preset               Swap the front-end scaffolding for the application
  serve                Serve the application on the PHP development server
  tinker               Interact with your application
  up                   Bring the application out of maintenance mode
 auth
  auth:clear-resets    Flush expired password reset tokens
 cache
  cache:clear          Flush the application cache
  cache:forget         Remove an item from the cache
  cache:table          Create a migration for the cache database table
 config
  config:cache         Create a cache file for faster configuration loading
  config:clear         Remove the configuration cache file
 db
  db:seed              Seed the database with records
  db:wipe              Drop all tables, views, and types
 event
  event:cache          Discover and cache the application's events and listeners
  event:clear          Clear all cached events and listeners
  event:generate       Generate the missing events and listeners based on registration
  event:list           List the application's events and listeners
 flare
  flare:test           Send a test notification to Flare
 key
  key:generate         Set the application key
 make
  make:channel         Create a new channel class
  make:command         Create a new Artisan command
  make:controller      Create a new controller class
  make:event           Create a new event class
  make:exception       Create a new custom exception class
  make:factory         Create a new model factory
  make:job             Create a new job class
  make:listener        Create a new event listener class
  make:mail            Create a new email class
  make:middleware      Create a new middleware class
  make:migration       Create a new migration file
  make:model           Create a new Eloquent model class
  make:notification    Create a new notification class
  make:observer        Create a new observer class
  make:policy          Create a new policy class
  make:provider        Create a new service provider class
  make:request         Create a new form request class
  make:resource        Create a new resource
  make:rule            Create a new validation rule
  make:seeder          Create a new seeder class
  make:test            Create a new test class
 migrate
  migrate:fresh        Drop all tables and re-run all migrations
  migrate:install      Create the migration repository
  migrate:refresh      Reset and re-run all migrations
  migrate:reset        Rollback all database migrations
  migrate:rollback     Rollback the last database migration
  migrate:status       Show the status of each migration
 notifications
  notifications:table  Create a migration for the notifications table
 optimize
  optimize:clear       Remove the cached bootstrap files
 package
  package:discover     Rebuild the cached package manifest
 queue
  queue:failed         List all of the failed queue jobs
  queue:failed-table   Create a migration for the failed queue jobs database table
  queue:flush          Flush all of the failed queue jobs
  queue:forget         Delete a failed queue job
  queue:listen         Listen to a given queue
  queue:restart        Restart queue worker daemons after their current job
  queue:retry          Retry a failed queue job
  queue:table          Create a migration for the queue jobs database table
  queue:work           Start processing jobs on the queue as a daemon
 route
  route:cache          Create a route cache file for faster route registration
  route:clear          Remove the route cache file
  route:list           List all registered routes
 schedule
  schedule:run         Run the scheduled commands
 session
  session:table        Create a migration for the session database table
 storage
  storage:link         Create a symbolic link from "public/storage" to "storage/app/public"
 vendor
  vendor:publish       Publish any publishable assets from vendor packages
 view
  view:cache           Compile all of the application's Blade templates
  view:clear           Clear all compiled view files
```

Como puedes notar ya no existe dicho comando

```
app:name Set the application namespace
```

**Explicacion**

- El comando fue removido al no ser considerado de mucha utilidad y pensado para existir como un paquete de terceros; puedes leer mas de lo que comento en este [pull request](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/27575)
- De acuerdo con [Dries Vints](https://github.com/driesvints), parte del equipo oficial de Laravel, indica que hace mas sentido cambiar el namespace de un paquete y no así de una aplicación entera para que de este modo más gente use el namespace por defecto `App`
- Sin embargo el usuario [isluewell](https://github.com/isluewell), propone en el mismo hilo un gist donde comparte la clase del archivo `Appname` para volver a tener disponible este comando, aquí el recurso oficial [AppName](https://gist.github.com/isluewell/b824c0aef32f5007170fcd0d8498b657)

Comment: Debo felicitarlo por su respuesta, ha ampliado el contenidoy profundizando la razon por la cual fue eliminado el comando app:name por parte del equipo que mantiene el framework Laravel

Answer (score 0):

**CORRECCION A LA RESPUESTA:** LA NUEVA VERSION DE LARAVLE 6.0 NO TIENE EL COMANDO: `artisan app:name`

Acabo de instalar la nueva version para confirmar la razon del problema porque yo estoy usando la 5.8 pero nunca pense que sacarian de la lista el comando `artisan el app:namespace`.

Para confirmar hice print de pantalla de la lista de comando Laravel 6.0

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la lista de comando artisan Laravel 5.8

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese cambio no aparece descrito en el release note de la version:

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/releases

**Para cambiar el namespace de laravel:** debes tipear desde la consola de comandos que se encuentra tu proyecto el siguiente comando:

```
php artisan app:name cursos
```

Donde `curso` sera ahora el nuevo nombre del namespace asigando.

**Ejemplo:**

yo uso visual studio code con Laravel 5.8 y abro el terminal para cambiar el `namespace`, aqui tengo un abieto un **controlador** y su nombre de `namespace` es `app`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ejecutar el comando artisan desde la terminal este muestra el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este cambia automaticamente el namespace de las clases involucradas como: controladores y modelos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Consideraciones:** La mayoria de los ejemplos que veras en Laravel usan el namespace que viene configurador por **defecto App** por lo cual, debes tener presente que has personalizado tu Laravel y al llamar un modelo para un controlador o migracion deberas usar el nuevo nombre de namespace que has asignado.

Comment: Probé de la comando desde Laravel 6 y me regresa el error que expone el OP mientras que en versiones inferiores funciona, alguna recomendación?

Comment: Acabo de revisar instalando la version de Laravel 6.0 y me dio cuenta que sacaron el comando app:namespace de la lista de artisan. cosa que no aparece en el Release Notes... acabo de poner la aclaratoria en la respuesta

Comment: Entonces tu respuesta ya no aplica amigo y solo debería quedar como comentario para indicar la situacion ya que tu aporte es sobre 5.8 y el OP usa la 6

Answer (score 0):

Escribe en tu `CMD` este comando y agregalo la librería:

```
composer require andrey-helldar/laravel-app --dev
```